# How can I sign a IPA programmatically?

Tags: ios, ipa, mobileprovision

Does anybody know how can I sign a IPA programatically. I know the security command on Mac OS X but I don't want to use them because it only works on Mac OS X. Is there any other way to sign a IPA?

Answer (score 0):

You can only to that on macOS. I recommend [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools), great tools to automate these things.

Comment: But for example the application [Cydia Impactor](http://www.cydiaimpactor.com/) can sideload a IPA to a iOS device. That also works on Windows.